# EF 6 Annotation to prevent relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to figure out a way to prevent Entity Framework from creating a relationship between two of my tables. In one table I have a property called "BlogId", while at the same time I have a table called "Blog". Entity Framework therefore creates a relationship between them, and I'm wondering if there's anyway to prevent it from doing this?

I realise simply making the two have a relation would be a simple fix, but I've had a lot of problems today with these two tables so I've decided to not have them related, and instead manage it myself.

Code-First & Automatic Migrations

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using Code First? Model First? As far as I'm aware, EF doesn't spot relations automatically based on a name. Unless there's an update I've missed recently. I'd expect it to be defined somewhere (the POCO classes for Code First, or the .edmx for Model First).

Comment: EF figure out the relations based on an object references and not by primitive properties. Of course unless you setup the relation in the migration files. Post the relevant code for those entities.

Comment: Care to explain why you need that?

Comment: I'm using Code-First with Automatic Migrations. I apologize for the lack of info.

I've deleted the entire database and had Entity Framework re-generate it, but it still has that relation between that property. So I need a way to tell it NOT to make the relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `[NotMapped()]` annotation to your `Blog` property and leave the `BlogId` as it is.

Comment: Thank you, I found a way to go around the issue, but I'm sure I'll be using that annotation if the problem comes up again. Thanks!